# How do you change this page's sourcecode to make its content and menu div expand together?

Tags: html, css

On my page http://kuerzer.de/UAGRb3tOQ I want to have only one scrolling bar at the outer right. I want the whole form to expand if its content part expands.

If the content div expands, I want the menu on the right side stay on top. If the menu is longer than the content, the content should stay on top.

How would you do it using my source code?

Note: Please leave the shortening url intact as I don't want my webpage-url to be seen here publicly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the second part of the question, but for this part:

```
I want to have only one scrolling bar at the outer right. 
I want the whole form to expand if it's content part expands.
```

Change

```
#Layer-3 {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

By either removing it, or changing it to

```
#Layer-3 {
    overflow: none;
}
```

As a general overview, your main HTML should look something like:

```
<div class="main_body">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="content"></div>
        <div class="navigation"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the page, there is a problem doing this.

Comment: Second part: Right side expands->left side stays on top. Left side expands->right side stays on top. And all the time the footer remains at the bottom of both.

Comment: The problem is that the middle div that holds the side navigation doesn't contain the content. So the main rounded image will only expand to fill its child containers, which is only the right menu. You need to put the left content inside the middle div content, which you call `Layer-1001`

Comment: http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/1967/flickral.jpg

Comment: Exactly - See on the top right of your image, the navigation ends which makes the rounded footer image show? That's because the of my comment. Modify your HTML so it resembles something like my edited answer, this will cause the `Layer-1001` div to expand when the content expands.

Comment: @Koryphäe - Glad to help :) If I've answered your question, can you mark my answer as accepted? Thanks.